# Replacing base values in R by mean values from multiple rows

Tags: r, dataset, aggregate

I am new to R. Having a problem to solve this dataset.

```
df
ID     Time Value
1001    -34 3.3
1001    14  4.2
1002    -34 3.8
1002    14  6.5
1004    -18 4.1
1004    -11 3.4
1004    37  3.8
1005    -16 5.8
1005    -10 6.0
1005    14  8.1
1006    -20 16.1
1006    -10 14.1
1006    158 14.1
1007    -35 7.1
1007    -20 4.6
1007    -20 5.1
1007    10  5.0
```

For each ID, if there are more than one reading for negative time, replace the value with the mean and set the time to 0. The resulting dataset should be:

```
df1
ID      Time   Value
1001    0   3.3
1001    14  4.2
1002    0   3.8
1002    14  6.5
1004    0   3.75
1004    37  3.8
1005    0   5.9
1005    14  8.1
1006    0   15.1
1006    158 14.1
1007    0   5.6
1007    10  5.0
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is your output value for "1007" incorrect? You have `1007    0   5.7` bit `mean(c(7.1,4.6,5.1)) != 5.7`, it's 5.6. Or am I misinterpreting what you want?

Comment: You are right. Should be 5.6. This is due to some other decimal values after the data.

Comment: And I think ID 1004 should be 3.75 for time 0. you should edit your original question to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be pretty fast if you have lots of data.

```
#Convert to data.table object
require("data.table")
dt <- data.table(df)

#Label Negative values
dt[,Neg:=(Time<0)*1]

#Make positive and negative datasets
dt1 <- dt[Neg==0]
dt2 <- dt[Neg==1,list(Time=0,Value=mean(Value,na.rm=T),Neg=1),by="ID"]

#Recombine them together
df.final <- rbindlist(list(dt1,dt2))[order(ID,Time)]
```

Here is the result

```
#       ID Time Value Neg
#  1: 1001    0  3.30   1
#  2: 1001   14  4.20   0
#  3: 1002    0  3.80   1
#  4: 1002   14  6.50   0
#  5: 1004    0  3.75   1
#  6: 1004   37  3.80   0
#  7: 1005    0  5.90   1
#  8: 1005   14  8.10   0
#  9: 1006    0 15.10   1
# 10: 1006  158 14.10   0
# 11: 1007    0  5.60   1
# 12: 1007   10  5.00   0
```

---

You can also put it all together in a one-liner to get a similar answer as follows:

```
dt[, list(Time=Time[1] * tt, 
          Value = if(tt) Value else mean(Value)), 
   by=list(ID, tt=Time>0)]
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Very helpful in solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution.

```
#copy raw data
dx <- df

#find time<0
lz <- dx$Time<0

#set those to tim 0
dx$Time[lz] <- 0

#update means for each ID for those values where time<0
dx$Value[lz] <- ave(dx$Value, dx$ID, lz, FUN=mean)[lz]

#remove duplicated time<0 values
dx<- dx[!(duplicated(dd$ID, lz) & lz), ]
```

And the results...

```
     ID Time Value
1  1001    0  3.30
2  1001   14  4.20
3  1002    0  3.80
4  1002   14  6.50
5  1004    0  3.75
7  1004   37  3.80
8  1005    0  5.90
10 1005   14  8.10
11 1006    0 15.10
13 1006  158 14.10
14 1007    0  5.60
17 1007   10  5.00
```